# Select job from RabbitMQ queue using some predefined ID?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, message-queue

I would appreciate your thoughts on this.

```
Node app 1 sends data to a RabbitMQ queue. The data contains a unique ID.

Node app 2 requests data with a specific ID from the RabbitMQ queue.
```

So as you can see, I need to be able to select specific messages from the queue, rather than just the next available message.

Is this possible? How can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use either header or topic exchange - look for `Exchanges and Exchange Types` [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html). For topic there is also tutorial [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html).

Answer (score 0):

no directly from a single queue

if you have 3 messages in a queue, those messages will come out of that queue in order: first in, first out.

[the "selective consumer" pattern](http://derickbailey.com/2015/07/22/airport-baggage-claims-selective-consumers-and-rabbitmq-anti-patterns/) for retrieving a message by some value, from a queue, is an anti-pattern in rabbitmq.

to accomplish what you want, you need to create an exchange / queue / binding setup that sends your message to a specific queue so that your specific consumer can handle it.